# Julia TCP select

Tags: sockets, julia

I have one problem with TCP connection.

I have made server like:

```
 server = listen(5000)
  sock = accept(server)
    while isopen(sock)
     yes=read(sock,Float64,2)
     println(yes)
   end
```

I want that it will continually print [0.0,0.0] when there is nothing to read, otherwise it will print what it reads from server. 
This will go to loop(trying to read something), if there is nothing to read or it crashes.
I try to do this with task like:

```
begin
 server = listen(5000)
 while true
   sock = accept(server)
    while isopen(sock)
     yes=read(sock,Float64,2)
     println(yes)
   end
  println([0.0,0.0])
 end
end
```

but this will only print what it reads. I'm making connection with other console and ride through consol:

```
clientside=connect(5000)
write(clientside,[2.0,2.0])
```

So I'm trying to make server that prints [0.0,0.0], if there is nothing to read and it will print what it reads when there is something to read. 
Any good ideas?

Comment: You mean TCP right? Not TPC?
Took me a while.

Comment: D'oh! Yes, my mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe, one strategy to make the server is to run the `accept / print` block asynchronously (since the `accept` call blocks the main thread).

Following the tutorial ["Using TCP Sockets in Julia"](http://blog.leahhanson.us/post/julia/julia-sockets.html), one way to make the server is:

```
notwaiting = true
server = listen(5000)
while true  
    if notwaiting
        notwaiting = false
        # Runs accept async (does not block the main thread)
        @async begin
            sock = accept(server)
            ret = read(sock, Float64, 2)
            println(ret)
            global notwaiting = true
        end        
    end
    println([0.0, 0.0])
    sleep(1) # slow down the loop
end
```

The variable `notwaiting` makes the `async` block runs only once per connection (without it, the server runs a kind of "race condition").

Testing it with two calls to the client program, produces the following output:

```
C:\research\stackoverflow\EN-US>julia s.jl
[0.0,0.0]
[0.0,0.0]
[0.0,0.0]
[0.0,0.0]
[2.0,2.0]
[0.0,0.0]
[0.0,0.0]
[0.0,0.0]
[2.0,2.0]
[0.0,0.0]
[0.0,0.0]
[0.0,0.0]
```

<sub>tested with Julia Version 0.5.0-rc3+0</sub>

Comment: This is good. One problem still is that you  can only send one line with this. I tried while loop writing to the connection(if you can say so), but the listening server reads only first line. I can work with this also, this is what i wanted. Thanks.