# Julia TCP server and connection

Tags: sockets, tcp, server, julia

I asked how to make TCP server that send data all the time in here: [Julia TCP select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39372430/julia-tcp-select/39382817#39382817) and it works great. I now I have new problem, so I thought to start new conversation.

I did this kind of connection like on the picture: [image]

So Sender sends sometimes something to server 1 and server 1  reads it and updates what to send to server 2 and Server 2 calculates numbers and communicates with C program.

Here is my server 1 code:

```
notwaiting = true
message  = zeros(10,14)
server = listen(5001)
connection = connect(5003)
    
while true
    if notwaiting
        notwaiting = false
        # Runs accept async (does not block the main thread)
        @async begin
            sock = accept(server)
            reply= read(sock, Float64, 11)
            message[:,convert(Int64,reply[1])] = reply[2:11]
    
            write(connection,reshape(message,140))
            global notwaiting = true
        end
    end
    write(connection,reshape(message,140))
    
    if message[1,1] == -1.0
        close(connection)
        close(server)
        break
    end
    sleep(0.01) # slow down the loop
end
```

Sender is:

```
Connection2= connect(5001)
message = [2.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0]
write(Connection2,message)
close(Connection2)
```

And server 2 is like this:

```
function Server2_connection()
    println("Waiting for connection")
    server2 = listen(5003)

    conn_2 = accept(server2)

    while isopen(conn_2)
        try
            message_server2 = round(read(conn_2,Float64,140),3)

            ins_matrix = reshape(message_server2[1:140],10,14)

        catch e
            println("caught an error $e")
            break
        end
    end

    println("Connection closed")
    close(conn)
    close(server)
end
```

The problem is that everything together is really heavy. I mean that I can send 2 messages from sender and everything is running really slow. I can run the whole thing 10-15s and then it freezes. All the connections work, but really slowly. My question is am I missing something or have something that makes the servers really slow? How can I code this better way?

Comment: Any particular reason you're not using [Julia's parallel tools](http://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/parallel-computing/) for remote calling/remote evaluation?

Comment: I could not reproduce the slowness nor the freeze (running the test for about 5 min and sending 10 messages). I made the test with all programs running Julia 0.5+rc3 on a Windows system and there was no slowness. Even moving server2 to a Mac (connected over an wi-fi network) servers 1 and 2 ran ok. Maybe it's a version's or environment's problem? (e.g.: OS, hardware, network, ...)

Comment: What to you mean? Can you be explain more specifically what to you  mean @FelipeLema

Comment: I'm using Julia 0.4.6 and atom editor. Good to here that it can work. @Gomiero

Comment: @pinq oh, nevermind, I thought the remote server was a julia server that called for a C program. Now I see I was mistaken.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have anymore problem with slowness. I got help from julia-users google forum and on of them(Tanmay K. Mohapatra) wrote better code for same purpose: https://gist.github.com/tanmaykm/c2ab61a52cc5afa0e54fe61905a48ef1 It works 
same way.

One problem with both codes is that they don't close connections properly. If server 2 goes down, the server 1 gets writing error and server 1 stays in listen mode.

Other ways it works. Thanks to Tanmay!

**Edit:** found the slower....the thing what should slow things down, did it. The sleep command did slow things down, but it slowed down more than I expected. If I had sleep variable 0.001 seconds, it will slow down the whole system like 0.014s. So I removed sleep command and it works fine.